# Getting a count of results with join, in active record

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

Conider this simple query:

```
$this->db->join('bids','bids.bid_for = request_quote.quoteid','left');
```

Is there any way possible to alter it, so instead of joining the result, it would instead join the COUNT of all bids it find?

I could rewrite this in plain SQL, but it is a part of bigger query, which I dont want to rewrite in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Tough one. I've looked at the CI's source code, and I don't see a "hack" for that.
Perhaps you could use this CI's method:

```
$this->db->count_all_results();
```

Comment: You see that will just count all results that I get from main query, it wont care about the join results, if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after messing around for couple hours I got it to work, so ill share it just in case anyone need it again:

```
    public function getAllJobsByUserId($userid){
        $this->db->select('quoteid')->select('quoteby')->select('country_from')
    ->select('country_to')->select('city_from')->select('city_to')
    ->select('countries.country_name, countries_to.country_name AS     country_name_to')
        ->select('COUNT(\'bids.bid_id\') as bid_count');
        $this->db->from('request_quote');
        $this->db->where('quoteby',$userid);
        $this->db->join('countries','countries.country_id = request_quote.country_from');
        $this->db->join('countries as countries_to','countries_to.country_id = request_quote.country_to');
        $this->db->join('bids as bid_count','bid_count.bid_for = request_quote.quoteid','outter');
        $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    }
```

This seem to work. But still in future ill probably write more complex queries in straight up SQL :)

Comment: ok actually this doesnt work as expected. It only returns one result ever.